# How to validate multiple inputs with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate for example 6 inputs (`I can create more than 100`) these inputs are created dynamically, the problem here is for example `the first two input values must be between 0 and 10, then other two between 5 and 10 and the last two inputs between 3 and 5`. What I do is validate this with `IF` but like I said I can create more than 100 inputs which means a lot of code, here is what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#create').change(function () {
    draw();
  });
  
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    validate();
  });
});

function draw() {
  var total = $('#create').val();
  var html = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < total; x++) {
    html += '<input id="InputNum' + x + '" />';
  }
  $('#draw').html(html);
}

function validate() {
  var Input1 = $('#InputNum0').val();
  var Input2 = $('#InputNum1').val();
  var Input3 = $('#InputNum2').val();
  var Input4 = $('#InputNum3').val();
  
  if (Input1 < 5 && Input1 >0 && Input2 < 5 && Input2 > 0)
    alert("Hello");
  else
    alert("Value must be between 0-5");
  
  if (Input3 < 15 && Input3 > 5 && Input4 < 15 && Input4 > 5 )
    alert("Hello");
  else
    alert("Value must be between 5-15");
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="create">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option>6</option>
<select />
  
  <div id="draw">
  </div>
  
  <button id="btn">Valida</button>
```

I want to know if exists a simple way to do this instead using an if for every input I want to check?

Comment: Do you want to validate the first 2 inputs with `0-5` and last 2 inputs with `3-5` and the rest inputs with `5-10` even when there are 100 inputs in total?

Comment: @nstungcom Yes! that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Use eq() function.

```
$("input").eq(-2) // before last element
$("input").eq(-1) // last element
```